# Has Justin Bieber written the 'melody' of any of his songs?

Tags: electronic-music

In the album "My World 2.0", **Justin Bieber** has sung some of the biggest hits such as *'Baby'*, *'Somebody to Love'*.

---Has he written the lyrics of these two songs by himself (without others' help) ?

---Has he written the 'melody' of these two songs?

Comment: can anyone respond please ?

Comment: @100m, have you tried to perform research by yourself? Why not check wikipedia at least?

Answer (score 4):

Let me just quote the Wikipedia:

> Baby" was written by Bieber with Christopher "Tricky" Stewart and Terius "The-Dream" Nash, both of whom worked with Bieber on "One Time", R&B singer and The-Dream's then wife Christina Milian and labelmate, Ludacris.[3] When asked how the collaboration initially came about, Bieber said, "[Ludacris and I] both live in Atlanta. I met him a year prior to this and we figured it was a perfect collaboration for him, so we invited him out to do it." Bieber first premiered the song performing on MuchMusic on December 28, 2009.[4] A few days before the release of the single, Bieber posted an acoustic version of the song to his YouTube with his guitarist Dan Kanterr, similar to the way he did with "Favorite Girl". Billboard said that: "Bieber delivers his characteristically clean vocals with conviction: "My first love broke my heart for the first time / and I'm like, 'baby, baby, baby, no!' I thought you'd always be mine."[5] Also in a review of the acoustic version Bill Lamb of About.com said that "I think the vocals here will convince some that Justin Bieber really does have the vocal chops."[6]

Comment: Hi. I just searched on Wikipedia and so far did Not find any song which is written ONLY by Justin Bieber. He 'co-wrote' the songs. And it's not clear how much input he has compared to others in a particular song. 
What about the melody of the songs? Did he also Co-wrote the melody?

Comment: @100fm, the problem is, we don't know. We have the same source of information that you have, Internet and Wikipedia. Why are you so interested in this question? Are you participate in some heated discussion about artist capabilities of Justin Bieber?

Comment: actually I am a fan of him, thats why I want to know that. 
Does 'writing a song' mean writing the lyrics ? or, writing both lyrics and melody?

Comment: @100fm, writing a song may mean both or nothing, it depends. For example, the are songs where singer did not write any lyrics or melody, or any actual music, he just sang it, and got all the the credit. And it's perfectly OK scenario in music.

Comment: what is the word in English language for the person who writes melody of a song?

Comment: I think it's a Composer

Comment: If it is 'Composer', then what is meant by Producer?

Comment: Producer perform a lot of functions, just read this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_producer

Comment: Another word in English for someone who only writes the melody of a song is "songwriter" or maybe "co-writer". There's not much distinction. In fact, sometimes people get writing credit even though they created no music or lyrics at all. Credit is sometimes more of a business decision than an artistic one.